# Finding path in a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, path-finding

I am working on a project and I've found myself in a position where I have a `n x n` `char` array of signs `a,b or c` I have to check if there is a path of `b`'s between the first and the last row. 
Example YES input:

[image]

I am stuck at this point? Should I adapt some well-known algorithm for graph searching or is there any better way of solving this problem? Should I add a `bool` array to mark which cell I  have visited? 
Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: How do you define a path?

Comment: How can you move? Only down, left and right, or up as well? What about diagonally?

Comment: @Dukeling Actually, to give you more details, in my problem you can go down, up, to the left or right, but also NE and SW (the only prohibited neighbors are NW and SE) since the table is a representation of hexagonal grid :) Decided to omit this info as it is slightly irrelevant to the subject of my problem (I could easily change the algorithm with different neighbor cell definitions)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should adopt a graph algorithm for finding the path from a source to the target. In your case you have multiple sources (all 'b's in the first row) and multiple targets ('b's in the last row).

Shortest path on an unweighted graph can be solved pretty efficiently by the easily implemented [**BFS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Only difference to handle multiple sources is to initialize the queue with all the 'b's on the first line (and not a single node).

In your graph every 'b' cell is a node, there is an edge between every two adjacent 'b' cells.

Note that BFS is complete (always finds a solution if one exists) and optimal (finds shortest path).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to allocate an equally sized, zero filled 2D array, mark the start points, and do a flood fill using the `char` array as a guide. When the flood fill terminates, you can easily check whether an end point has been marked.

A flood fill may be implemented in several ways, how you do it doesn't really matter as long as your problem size is small.

- Generally, the easiest way is to do it in a recursive fashion. The only problem with a recursive flood fill is the huge recursion depth that can result, so it really depends on the problem size whether a recursive version is applicable.
- If time is not important, you may simply do it iteratively, going through the entire array several times, marking points that have marked neighbours and are `b`s, until an iteration does not mark any point.
- If you need to handle huge arrays efficiently, you should go for a breadth-first flood fill, keeping a queue of frontier pixels which you process in a first-in-first-out manner.